# pass html table row data to arraylist of object

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td><input type="hidden" value ="flag"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" value ="orange"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" value ="1.00"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" value ="5"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="hidden" value ="flag"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" value ="apple"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" value ="1.00"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" value ="5"/></td>
</tr>
</table>

table.find('tr').each(function(i){
    var $tds = $(this).find('td input');
    var $tdhid = $(this).find('td input[type="text"]');
    var hidden = $tdhid.eq(0).val();

    var a = $tds.eq(0).val();
    var b = $tds.eq(1).val();
    var c = $tds.eq(2).val();
}
```

The above function get the table row data, orange and 5, and i want it to save to arraylist as one item or object. I want array like this :

```
Arraylist <Fruits> Arr;
Arr[0] = {orange,1.0,flag,5}
Arr[1] = {apple,5}
```

Any help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Yvy9s/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to `$.map()` at this context to finish up your job cleaner,

```
var array = $.map($('table tr'),function(val,i){
  var obj = {}, tds = $(val).find('td');
  obj[tds.filter(':first').text()] = tds.filter(':last').text();
  return obj;
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8kP9y/)

As per your new requirement you can use this,

```
var array = $.map($('table tr'), function (val, i) {
    var obj = {}, inputs = $(val).find('td input:not(:hidden)');
    obj[inputs.filter(':first').val()] = $.map(inputs.not(':first'), function (val, i) {
        return val.value;
    });
    return obj;
});
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, but JSON(T.T) is a new technology to me is that only use for printing out?

Comment: I edit you fiddle  i cant seem it to work using input http://jsfiddle.net/8kP9y/2/

Comment: thanks, just want to as if getting the cell data is hard-coded? what if have 3 td? see this http://jsfiddle.net/8kP9y/4/

Comment: @Niang How would you want to frame the object..? since an object needs one key as well as one value.. But your new markup has 3 inputs..

Comment: Actually sir I want to have one key,and many values. for example,the key is orange, and the values have still orange(or doesnt have),1.0,5

Comment: yes! i want to cry. Thats what i want. I will ask you again sir later.please.

Comment: i want that array to be pass on my java servlet, i just dont know how can i set that array to my request,$('#save').on("click",function(){//mapping goes here});

Comment: @Niang Just pass it as a JSON to the server, but frankly i did work on java before one year. i cannot direct you in a right way now. Just ask the question tagged with java servlet.

Answer (score 0):

```
var _arrFruits = [];
table.find('tr').each(function (i) {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td input');
    var a = $tds.eq(0).val();
    var b = $tds.eq(1).val();
    //assuming you are getting the correct values of a and b
    _arrFruits.push({
        a: b
    });
}
```

Comment: what if i have other data, can i used `_arrFruits.push({a : b :c});`

Comment: please see my edited post, i dont want to have key value pair, but a key with many values

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an array of arrays, then use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) like

```
var array = table.find('tr').map(function (i) {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td');
    return [[$tds.eq(0).text(), $tds.eq(1).text()]]
}).get();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Yvy9s/)

Comment: Hi sir @Arun P Johny thanks  for you answer, but JSON(T.T) is a new technology to me is that only use for printing out?